# Pygmented code showing up as a list

Tags: python, django, pygments

I'm using [django-pygments](https://github.com/odeoncg/django-pygments) and am trying to us it like so (`base.html`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load pygmentify %}
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="{% static 'django_pygments/css/pygments_default.css' %}" type="text/css">
</head>
<div class="row">
    <div id="mainbody" class="small-12 large-8 large-offset-2 columns">
        <body>
        {% pygment %}
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
        {% endpygment %}

        </body>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar" class="small-12 large-2 columns">
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 large-8 large-offset-2 columns">
        {% block comments %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 large-2 columns">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I'm passing `{{ post.content|safe }}` into block content. The pigmented code comes out as such:

[image: codeimage]

I've tried changing the `<ol>` tags in the source code to `<ul>` but obviously that wasn't the issue. I also turned passed `linenos=False` and `True` but that only made it more weird as the line numbers aren't lined put correctly.

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you have to wrap your code block in `<pre lang="python"></pre>`?

Comment: I did that in the post itself. So in Django admin I created a test post and pasted the code above in between the `pre` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was a problem with my `css` style sheet. I tried changing it and now it looks normal.